# "Відтермінувати" чи "відстрочити"?

Tags: вибір-слова, дієслова, legal-terms

Терміни [строк](http://sum.in.ua/s/strok) і [термін](http://sum.in.ua/s/termin) вживаються  як синоніми в українській мові. Однак, з дієсловами не все так просто. В СУМі в 11 т. знаходжу слово [**відстрочити**](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidstrochuvaty), однак, немає слова **відтермінувати**. В СУМі в 20 т. є і [відтермінувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=182576&page=453) і [відстрочувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13919&page=450).

Чому є розбіжності між цими словниками? В офіційних документах бачимо вживання відстрочка, а не відтермінування. [Стаття 373. Відстрочка і розстрочка виконання, зміна чи встановлення способу і порядку виконання](http://radnuk.info/komentar/chpky/chpky-pozdil6/3414--373-----------.html), [Стаття 17. Відстрочка від призову на строкову військову службу](https://urist-ua.net/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%96_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B1%D1%83/%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%82%D1%8F_17/), [Стаття 33. Відстрочка або розстрочка виконання, встановлення чи зміна способу і порядку виконання рішення](http://protokol.com.ua/ua/pro_vikonavche_provadgennya_stattya_33/).

Отже, чи дієслова **відтермінувати і відстрочувати** є синонімами, чи можна вжвати лише 1 слово, чи вживання залежить від контексту?

Comment: Родич-питанньа: [Чи має запозичений термін **дедлайн** синоніми українського походження](/a/4053/585). Јак не дивно, але тамтешньа моја відповідь підходить і цьому питанньу.

Comment: Відтермінувати ніколи не зустрічав. Хоча слово інтуітивно зрозуміле.

Answer (score 2):

Відповідь на це питання можна знайти в [болзі професора Пономарева](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/ukrainian/ponomariv/2011/06/post-48.html), цитую:

> Друге: слів "очільник", "**відтерміновувати**", "меседж" немає в
> словниках. Чи є вони в мові, - запитує слухачка.
>
> Кожна мова
> розвивається. У ній весь час з'являються нові слова для понять, які ще
> не мають назв, або ці нові слова розширюють синонімічні гнізда.
> Словники не виходять щодня, тому не встигають фіксувати всіх нових
> слів. Слово "очільник" утворено від дієслова "очолювати", тобто,
> керувати, бути на чолі. Воно не суперечить законам українського
> словотвору і згодом з'явиться в словниках. Те саме можна сказати і про
> "**відтерміновувати**". Маємо синоніми "термін" і "строк". Від "строк"
> утворено "відстрочувати". Воно є в словниках. А тепер з'явилося й
> "відтерміновувати", тобто, перенести виконання на пізніший термін. А
> ось без слова "меседж" українська мова може цілком обійтися. По-нашому
> це буде "послання".

Тобто, як бачите, це слова синоніми, однак в СУМ-11 немає слова "відтермінувати", бо тоді його ще не так активно використовували, однак, це слово вже з'явилося в СУМ-20. Підтвердження того, що ці слова можуть бути синонімами я ще й знайшов на [цьому форумі](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/lofiversion/index.php?t53-500.html), однак не вважаю його за надійне джерело.

Та й згідно до того ж СУМ-20 - ці слова можуть бути синонімами, давайте глянемо на визначення дієслова ["відтерміновувати"](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=192859&page=453):

> Відкладати, затримувати якусь дію, виконання чого-небудь;
> **відстрочувати**

Answer (score 1):

З вікіпедії [Термін (час)](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD_(%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81)#%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%87%D0%BE_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%84%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F):

> #### Законодавчо зафіксоване розділення
>
> Норма ч. 1 ст. 251 ЦК України визначає *строк* як певний період у
>   часі, зі спливом якого пов'язана дія чи подія, яка має юридичне
>   значення.
>
> Відповідно до ч. 2 цієї статті законодавець вводить поняття *терміну*
>   як певного моменту в часі, з настанням якого пов'язана дія чи подія,
>   яка має юридичне значення.
>
> Відповідно до ст. 252 цього кодексу «*строк* визначається роками,
>   місяцями, тижнями, днями або годинами», тоді як «*термін* визначається
>   календарною датою або вказівкою на подію, яка має неминуче
>   настати».
>
> Аналогічні визначення містить ДСТУ 1.5:2003.

Вважаю вартим це перенести і на похідні слова. Тобто,

- відтермінувати - перенести на пізнішу дату,
- відстрочити - перенести на певний проміжок часу (годин, днів тощо).

Comment: Але фактично, чи ми переносимо на пізніший термін, чи ми подовжуємо строк — результат той самий (хоча акцент теоретично може бути різним; або хтось дуже доскіпливий може послідовно казати _відтермінувати_ — коли початково (в договорі чи десь) був зафіксований якийсь _термін_, а _відстрочити_ — коли початково був зафіксований якийсь _строк_).

Answer (score 0):

Із визначень поданих в СУМ-20 можна зробити висновок, що слова ***відтермінувати*** і ***відстрочувати*** не є синонімами. Оскільки **[відстрочувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=13919&page=450)** (*Переносити виконання або виплату чогось на пізніший термін.*)  має ширне значення ніж **[відтерміновувати](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=182576&page=453)** (*Відкладати, затримувати якусь дію, виконання чого-небудь*).

В **[Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8)** до слово ***відстрочувати*** подаються такі синоніми:

> ВІДКЛАДА́ТИ (призначати здійснення, проведення чого-небудь на інший
>   час), ПЕРЕНО́СИТИ, ВІДСТРО́ЧУВАТИ, ВІДТЯГА́ТИ, ВІДТЯ́ГУВАТИ,
>   ВІДВОЛІКА́ТИ *рідше*.

***Відтерміновувати/відтермінува́ти*** в словнику синонімів відсутнє.

На мою думку, слід розмежовувати вживання даних слів залежно від контексту. Якщо говоримо про перенесення часу виконання певної дії вживати **"відтермінування"**, про оплату - **"відстрочка"**.

Comment: А можете пояснити, чому Ви вирішили, що у _відстрочувати_ ширше значення, ніж у _відтерміновувати_? (Бо я перечитую ці два визначення в СУМ-20 і поки не бачу різниці.)